# while running vba script through cmd prompt getting error

Tags: vbscript

Hi Any one please help me..

while running the vba script i am getting error--object DoCmd need to create.

My script is given below..

```
ExecuteInsert
Sub ExecuteInsert()
    Dim sheetPath
    Dim dbs, DbFullName, acc
    Set acc = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    DbFullName = "D:\G\Diamond\FINAL MS-Access\Demo\MS-Access project.accdb"
    Set dbs = acc.DBEngine.OpenDatabase(DbFullName, False, False)

    dbs.Execute "Delete from TempRoadMap"

    sheetPath = "C:\Users\270784\Desktop\CSPRV scheduled work - 2014 through 1-26-14.xlsx"

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel97, "TempRoadMap", sheetPath, True

    MsgBox "Imported Sheet1 from " & sheetPath & " Successfully!"

    dbs.Execute "Delete from RoadMap"
    dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO [RoadMap] ( Release_Name,SPRF,SPRF_CC,Estimate_Type,PV_Work_ID,SPRF_Name,Estimate_Name,Project_Phase,CSPRV_Status,Scheduling_Status,Impact_Type,Onshore_Staffing_Restriction,Applications,Total_Appl_Estimate,Total_CQA_Estimate,Estimate_Total,Requested_Release,Item_Type,Path) SELECT [TempRoadMap.Release Name], [TempRoadMap.SPRF], [TempRoadMap.Estimate (SPRF-CC)],[TempRoadMap.Estimate Type],[TempRoadMap.PV Work ID],[TempRoadMap.SPRF Name],[TempRoadMap.Estimate Name],[TempRoadMap.Project Phase],[TempRoadMap.CSPRV Status],[TempRoadMap.Scheduling Status],[TempRoadMap.Impact Type],[TempRoadMap.Onshore Staffing Restriction],[TempRoadMap.Applications],[TempRoadMap.Total Appl Estimate],[TempRoadMap.Total CQA Estimate],[TempRoadMap.Estimate Total],[TempRoadMap.Requested Release],[TempRoadMap.Item Type],[TempRoadMap.Path] FROM [TempRoadMap] "
    dbs.Close

    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error?  I'm sure it's not "object DoCmd need to create"

Comment: What do you mean by "...through cmd prompt..."? Are you trying to run it as a VBScript file ("*.vbs")? If so, there are several things that will need to be changed to make it work.

Comment: I might be more inclined to answer your question if you accepted my answer on the other question you asked, which you copied and pasted the code and revised it, then reposted the same code here with a new question.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251045/microsoft-vbscript-compilation-error-expected-end-of-statement

Comment: As @Rich noted, it is good practice to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer that solves your problem.  Doing so encourages people to want to spend their time help you in general, gives you credibility on this site in particular, and only takes a few seconds.

Comment: @Blackhawk, actuuly i am running VBScript file ("*.vbs").

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "...through cmd prompt..." you mean to imply that you are running this script as part of a VBScript file, here are the changes you would want to make:

1. DoCmd is a child of an Access.Application, and it can only be referenced globally in the scope of an Access database.  To reference it in VBScript, you must explicitly use an Access.Application instance, which you have as variable `acc`. Modify the beginning of the DoCmd line like so:

   `acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`
2. VBScript won't recognize Access constants like `acImport` or `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel97`, so you will have to replace them with their actual values.  A quick look through msdn reveals that [acImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834402%28v=office.15%29.aspx) is `0` and acSpreadsheetTypeExcel97 doesn't exist, but [acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196017%28v=office.15%29.aspx) (Excel 97 format) is `8`. So now the DoCmd line looks like:

   `acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet 0, 8, "TempRoadMap", sheetPath, True`
3. VBScript does not have `MsgBox` - this is only available through VBA.  Instead, you can use `Wscript.Echo`. For example, the last line would be: `WScript.Echo "Done"`

If you still have issues after making those changes, please let me know with a comment below.

Comment: After making the change Docmd TO acc.Docmd its throwing the error TransferSpreadsheet is not available now???

Comment: I am now giving that line as...

Comment: acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet  0, 8, "TempRoadMap", "D:\G\Diamond\FINAL MS-Access\Demo\MS-Access project.accdb", True

Now showing TransferSpreadsheet is not available  :( help me out to resolve this

Comment: @user2412576 You are calling the TransferSpreadsheet function incorrectly.  The FileName should be the name of the Excel document you want to import from.  Since it appears that you are trying to import from an Excel 2007ish file (*.xlsx), you will need to use the constant 10 for the second parameter.  So for example: `acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet 0, 10, "TempRoadMap", "C:\Users\270784\Desktop\CSPRV scheduled work - 2014 through 1-26-14.xlsx"` should work.

Answer (score 0):

VBScript certainly does have msgbox and echo is not part of vbscript but of Windows Scripting Host.