# Running the VBScript in Enterprise-Architect via command line

Tags: vbscript, enterprise-architect

I wrote a VBScript which will export the excel file(contains some elements information). But every time I need to open the EA to generate the excel.

For CI purpose I need to run the script from the command line. Is it possible to run the script which is present inside the enterprise architect via command line?

Comment: Rather than adding the answer to the question you should post it as answer to yourself. That might as well give you some upvote points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. In order access EA's API you need to have a running EA instance. You can access that from outside EA with something like

```
Dim Repository
Set EAapp = GetObject(, "EA.App") 
Set Repository = EAapp.repository
```

Or you just stay with the script in EA itself...

It is possible to work directly with EA's database bypassing the API. But that's a different story.

Comment: I have running EA instance and I tried to run the above lines in through VBS. But I am getting a compilation error in Dim Repository As EA.Repository line.Do i need to import any package for EAP.

Comment: Error : eap.vbs(9, 11) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement

Comment: `Expected end of statement ` is something you need to figure out yourself, please...

Comment: A quick google popped up this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251045/microsoft-vbscript-compilation-error-expected-end-of-statement

Comment: thanks for your response. I don't know VBS much, but the link you provided helps me a lot...

Comment: It is possible to work directly with EA's database bypassing the API - you mean SQL queries?

Comment: @geertbellekens Thanks for the fix. Those greedy Mikeysoft details... I have to make an update to my Scripting book...

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

From the reference of the qwerty_so [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56934385/7319413).

```
Option Explicit

On Error Resume Next

EaExample

Sub EaExample()   
  Dim App  
  Set App = GetObject(,"EA.App")
  dim currentPackage
  set currentPackage = App.Repository.GetPackageByGuid("{134E96EA-623E-410e-A13F-73DDDDA1E091}")
  MsgBox currentPackage.Name
 End Sub
```

Open the EAP instance and Run the script from the command line.